# CUDA: cascaded summation of all vector elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, cuda, addition, atomic

I have implemented a cascaded addition function for a large vector of float values on my GPU and my CPU. That simply means that all elements of this vector shell be summed up into one result. The CPU algorithm is quite trivial and works fine, but the GPU algorithm is always 35200 off the desired result.

The minimal working code for the algorithm and comparison to the CPU is below.

The output is always this:

```
CPU Time: 22.760059 ms, bandwidth: 3.514929 GB/s

GPU Time (improved): 12.077088 ms, bandwidth: 6.624114 GB/s
- CPU result does not match GPU result in improved atomic add.
   CPU: 10000000.000000, GPU: 10035200.000000, diff:-35200.000000
```

I checked it with cuda-memcheck but no errors occured in that run. I have tried many many different things but none of themworked. It if not due to the inaccuracy of the float datatype because I changed all floats to ints and still got the exact same result.

This is my code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reductionWithCudaImproved(float *result, const float *input);
__global__ void reductionKernelImproved(float *result, const float *input);
void reductionCPU(float *result, const float *input);

#define SIZE 10000000

#define TILE 32

#define ILP 8
#define BLOCK_X_IMPR (TILE / ILP)
#define BLOCK_Y_IMPR 32
#define BLOCK_COUNT_X_IMPR 100

int main()
{
    int i;
    float *input;
    float resultCPU, resultGPU;
    double cpuTime, cpuBandwidth;

    input = (float*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(float));
    resultCPU = 0.0;
    resultGPU = 0.0;

    srand((int)time(NULL));

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        input[i] = 1.0;

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    reductionCPU(&resultCPU, input);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    cpuTime = (diff.count() * 1000);
    cpuBandwidth = (sizeof(float) * SIZE * 2) / (cpuTime * 1000000);
    printf("CPU Time: %f ms, bandwidth: %f GB/s\n\n", cpuTime, cpuBandwidth);

    reductionWithCudaImproved(&resultGPU, input);

    if (resultCPU != resultGPU)
        printf("- CPU result does not match GPU result in improved atomic add. CPU: %f, GPU: %f, diff:%f\n\n", resultCPU, resultGPU, (resultCPU - resultGPU));
    else
        printf("+ CPU result matches GPU result in improved atomic add. CPU: %f, GPU: %f\n\n", resultCPU, resultGPU);

    return 0;
}

void reductionCPU(float *result, const float *input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        *result += input[i];
}

__global__ void reductionKernelImproved(float *result, const float *input)
{
    int i;
    int col = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x) * ILP;
    int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int index = row * blockDim.x * BLOCK_COUNT_X_IMPR + col;
    __shared__ float interResult;

    if (threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
        interResult = 0.0;

    __syncthreads();

#pragma unroll ILP
    for (i = 0; i < ILP; i++)
    {
        if (index < SIZE)
        {
            atomicAdd(&interResult, input[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
        atomicAdd(result, interResult);
}

void reductionWithCudaImproved(float *result, const float *input)
{
    dim3 dim_grid, dim_block;

    float *dev_input = 0;
    float *dev_result = 0;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsed = 0;
    double gpuBandwidth;

    dim_block.x = BLOCK_X_IMPR;
    dim_block.y = BLOCK_Y_IMPR;
    dim_block.z = 1;

    dim_grid.x = BLOCK_COUNT_X_IMPR;
    dim_grid.y = (int)ceil((float)SIZE / (float)(TILE * dim_block.y* BLOCK_COUNT_X_IMPR));
    dim_grid.z = 1;

    cudaSetDevice(0);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_input, SIZE * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_result, sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_input, input, SIZE * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_result, result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    cudaEventRecord(start);
    reductionKernelImproved << <dim_grid, dim_block >> >(dev_result, dev_input);

    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, start, stop);

    gpuBandwidth = (sizeof(float) * SIZE * 2) / (elapsed * 1000000);
    printf("GPU Time (improved): %f ms, bandwidth: %f GB/s\n", elapsed, gpuBandwidth);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(result, dev_result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_input);
    cudaFree(dev_result);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have overlapping indices in your kernel call:

```
int col = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x) * ILP;
int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
int index = row * blockDim.x * BLOCK_COUNT_X_IMPR + col;
```

If I am not mistaken, your blockDim.x = 4 and BLOCK_COUNT_X_IMPR = 100, so each row will jump 400 indices.
However, your col can go as high as 400 * 8.

Consider:

```
blockIdx = (12, 0)
threadIdx = (3, 0)
=> col = (12*4 + 3) * 8 = 408
   row = 0
   index = 408

blockIdx = (0, 0)
threadIdx = (1, 1)
=> col = (0*4 + 1) * 8 = 8
   row = 1
   index = 1 * 400 + 8 = 408
```

So I guess you should rewrite your index

```
// gridDim.x = BLOCK_COUNT_X_IMPR
int index = row * blockDim.x * gridDim.x * ILP + col;
```